# `pop-to-buffer` in other frame if file is already visited

Tags: buffers, frames

Say I have two frames open. Frame A is visiting a file `foo.org`. Calling `(pop-to-buffer "foo.org")` in the other frame (B) opens `foo.org` in frame B instead of moving the focus to frame A where that buffer is already open. Can this be configured (and how) to "jump" to frame A?

I appreciate that there are other functions that allow me to jump "across frames" but I'd like to adapt the behaviour of `pop-to-buffer` specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop-to-buffer` is essentially `display-buffer` with selecting the chosen window afterwards.

You can influence the behavior of `display-buffer` with display actions specified in several variables. See [the corresponding info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Choosing-Window.html) for a complete list of actions and variables.

I think you should configure `display-buffer-base-action` with your preferred display behavior.

`display-buffer-reuse-window` with the alist `(reusable-frames . 0)` avoids popping up the buffer in the already selected frame if it is shown on another frame.

Configure it with the following Elisp snippet in your config files or use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `display-buffer-base-action` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

```el
(setq display-buffer-base-action '(display-buffer-reuse-window (reusable-frames . 0)))
```

The list of available options for the `reusable-frames` entry of the alist is:

- **nil:** the selected frame (actually the last non-minibuffer frame)
- **A frame  :** just that frame
- **‘visible’:** all visible frames
- **0  :** all frames on the current terminal
- **t  :** all frames.